# 404 Not Found in django admin page when using django-non-rel for google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I am using python 2.7 and django 1.8 and django-non-rel to make my project run on google app engine for django non-rel.
When i open http://127.0.0.1:8000/ it works fine and takes me to the google app engine sdk page..
But when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ , I get error -

404 Not Found
The resource could not be found.

Please help me to set up the admin page.

My urls.py file is this -

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
import dbindexer

handler500 = 'djangotoolbox.errorviews.server_error'

# django admin
admin.autodiscover()

# search for dbindexes.py in all INSTALLED_APPS and load them
dbindexer.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'bookncart.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^bookncart/', include('bookncart.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url('^_ah/warmup$', 'djangoappengine.views.warmup'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The settings.py file is this -

```
# Django settings for bookncart project.

# Initialize App Engine and import the default settings (DB backend, etc.).
# If you want to use a different backend you have to remove all occurences
# of "djangoappengine" from this file.
from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
import os

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Activate django-dbindexer for the default database
DATABASES['native'] = DATABASES['default']
DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'dbindexer', 'TARGET': 'native'}
AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'indexes'

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = False

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'y*ik#rc7+ifd5&_^hc(yk-ca15ze^%ooltm_s)po^zyjzj$t9b'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # This loads the index definitions, so it has to come first
    'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookncart.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# This test runner captures stdout and associates tracebacks with their
# corresponding output. Helps a lot with print-debugging.
TEST_RUNNER = 'djangotoolbox.test.CapturingTestSuiteRunner'


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}


DEBUG = True
```

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: it defaults settings.py, tested

Comment: No still not working .. i am not able to access the admin page still.

Comment: 404 Not Found
The resource could not be found.